When npm install return "Cannot find module 'node:path'"
I'm installing an old project in a new macbook intel chip machine.And i install node-v18.20.4.pkg already.But i get wrong message from console.
Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/Cellar/node@18/18.20.4/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js
- /usr/local/Cellar/node@18/18.20.4/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/node@18/18.20.4/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/local/Cellar/node@18/18.20.4/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/node@18/18.20.4/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

I checked cli.js & npm-cli.js, they do exist in the message path.I‘ve tried many ways, cant't solve it.Any suggestions?What's the right config in .zshrc?

I think there might be some incompatibility issue with the newer version node with older version of npm. Could you check which version of npm module your mac is using?

node:path is a built-in module, and node: definitely works in the latest Node 18 release. So the fact that this is not working is very strange, and suggests to me that your Node installation is broken. (but could be wrong!)
